# React - Why did I need to do type coercion on my boolean

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting some data from my API into my React app like so:

`const { title, acknowledged } = dataFromApi;`

What I found was when I tried using that `acknowledged` - which is a boolean, the following conditional was always going into the false case i.e showing CrossIcon. On looking into the value of `acknowledged` I see nothing, just blank:

```
<Icon source={acknowledged ? TickIcon : CrossIcon} />
```

However when I do that type coercion using double `!!` like below it worked:

```
<Icon source={!!acknowledged ? TickIcon : CrossIcon} />
```

It works, however I have no idea why I had to do this, isn't Boolean a primitive type, why is this extra dressing needed?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can use typeof operator to see the type of acknowledged, it is probably not boolean as you think.

Comment: Are you sure this is a boolean? It looks like it could a boolean represented as a string like ‘true’ and now you are applying type coercion to cast it back to boolean. Can you run `console.log(typeof acknowledged);` to see what is really coming from your API?

Comment: I checked that already it is `boolean` - and reconfimed with console.log(typeof acknowledged);

Comment: what do you mean 'not working as expected' ?

Comment: @JiaSH have updated the post

Comment: I would check those things: 1. console.log(acknowledged, typeof acknowledge), 2. Log the variable at part of your code where you assign it (after getting it from the server, also log the parsed object), 3. Log the string that you are receiving from the API to see if it matches what you think it is. To further help you, you basically need to post the full code beginning with the request, all the way to your component.

Comment: As you have said in your post, you see blank as value of acknowledged so it is not a boolean. You are not fetching the acknowledged value correctly from your api. It is not relevant to usage of !!. Fix your dataFromApi.